continuous function sequence with compact support converging uniformly to continuous function with compact support is uniformly equicontinuous
The proposition is stated below:
Suppose $(f_n)$ is a sequence of continuous functions with compact support. $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to a continuous function $f$, whose closed support is also compact. Then $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded and uniformly equicontinuous.
My attempt: I have proved that $f_n$ is bounded and uniformly continuous for each $n$. Then I managed to prove the uniform boundedness of $(f_n)$. But I cannot prove the equicontinuity.
Please help me :)
Some definition: A closed support of a function $f(x)$ is the closure of $\{x\in \mathbb R\mid f(x)\neq 0\}$ in $\mathbb R$. If a closed support is compact, we say it is a compact support.
